# ¿Cómo puedo realizar un búcle utilizando el módulo de Python "pyautogui" y la función pyautogui.Onscreen() que pase hasta que se cumpla una condición?

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que me lleva a un website (específicamente el website para iniciar sesión en google) y luego escribe mi email en la casilla de iniciar sesión, para esto estoy usando mayormente el módulo pyautogui (que lo importé como "pe"), por ahora todo funciona bien excepto que el tiempo que tarda el website en cargar no es definitivo ya que depende de la velocidad de la conexión a internet.

Entonces quiero que mi programa NO escriba el email hasta que la página que termine de cargar, para esto intenté utilizar la función "locateOnScreen" para que mientras una imagen aparezca en la pantalla el programa espere, y que cuando ya la imagen NO aparezca en la pantalla proceda a escribir mi email.

Mi código se ve de esta forma ahora mismo:

```
refreshcords = pe.locateCenterOnScreen('refresh.png')
notdonecords = pe.locateCenterOnScreen('notdone.png')

def winstonsignin():
    messagebox.showinfo('Espere...', 'Espere un momento por favor, no haga click.')
    time.sleep(0.7)
    try: 
        subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', '--incognito'])
        time.sleep(1)
        pe.hotkey('win', 'up')
    except:
        os.startfile('chrome')
        time.sleep(1)
        pe.hotkey('win', 'up')
        time.sleep(0.4)
        pe.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'n')
        time.sleep(0.4)
        pe.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
        time.sleep(0.4)
        pe.hotkey('ctrl', 'w')
        time.sleep(0.4)
    pe.typewrite("url")
    pe.hotkey('enter')
    while (True):
        if pe.onScreen(notdonecords) == True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            pe.typewrite('email')
            break
```

El problema con esto es que no cumple la función, o sea, no reconoce si la imagen está en la pantalla o no, y tampoco escribe el email.

Esta es la imagen en cuestión:
[image: notdone.png]

Ese el el simbolo de X que reemplaza el ícono de refrescar la página cuando la página no ha cargado, mi idea era que si esa imagen estaba en la pantalla en vez del ícono de refrescar, significaba que la página no había cargado. Por favor ayúdenme.

Comment: Por favor indenta correctamente el código

Comment: Listo. Ya indenté correctamente el código.

Comment: El código ya estaba indentado correctamente en mi código original, eso fue un error de redacción en mi pregunta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucioné el problema, en vez de esperar a que aparezca el símbolo de refrescar aparezca, me di cuenta de que este símbolo aparece cuando Google termina de cargar, y es muchísimo más fácil de identificar. Entonces usando este código funcionó lo que quería lograr:

```
    while waitingloop == 1:
        if pe.locateCenterOnScreen('googleloaded.png') == None:
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            pe.typewrite('email')
            break
```

[image: googlecargó]

Comment: Usar selenium seria mejor

Comment: Correcto. Tienes razón.